# QSettings не сохраняет информацию после закрытия программы

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qsettings

Программа с `QTableView`, вписываются в таблицу два параметра `Name` и `Points`. Пытался сохранять информацию при помощи `QSettings`, однако при выходе из программы ничего не сохраняется даже при наличии `.ini` файла.

Изменено: насколько я понял, я просто не подгружаю настройки. отсюда вопрос, как сделать сохранение и подгрузку настроек?

**`Counter.py`**

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class CustomTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def KeyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print("Key_Enter ")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print("Key_Return ")


class NumberSortModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def lessThan(self, left_index: "QModelIndex",
                 right_index: "QModelIndex") -> bool:

        left_var: str = left_index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        right_var: str = right_index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

        try:
            return float(left_var) < float(right_var)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass

        try:
            return left_var < right_var
        except TypeError: 
            return True


class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Formula1", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self.setFont(font)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name" , "Points"])

        self.proxy = NumberSortModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.table = CustomTableView(self)
        self.table.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update")                           
        update_button.clicked.connect(self.on_update_button)                      
        sort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sort")

        self.qlineedit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit_name.resize(24, 80)
        self.qlineedit_points = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit_points.resize(24, 80)

        horisontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit_name, stretch=1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit_points, stretch=1)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(update_button)                                 
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(sort_button)
        horisontal_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        grid_layout.addLayout(horisontal_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)

        settings = QtCore.QSettings("settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("Name", "Points")
        settings.sync()

    def on_update_button(self):
        name = self.qlineedit_name.text().strip()
        point = self.qlineedit_points.text().strip() if self.qlineedit_points.text().strip() else '0'
        if not point.isdigit():
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните правильно поле ввода Points!')
            return msg

        if not name:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните поле ввода Name!')
            return msg
        rows  = self.table.model().rowCount()
        add_record = True
        for row in range(rows):
            if name == self.proxy.data(self.proxy.index(row, 0)):
                #print(name)
                add_record = False
                row_edit = row
                break

        if add_record:       
            if self.table.selectedIndexes():
                row = self.table.selectedIndexes()[-1].row()
                self.model.insertRow(row+1, [QtGui.QStandardItem(name), 
                                      QtGui.QStandardItem(point)])                  

            else:
                self.model.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(name), 
                                      QtGui.QStandardItem(point)])            
        else:                 
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(row_edit, 1), point, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        
        self.qlineedit_name.clear()
        self.qlineedit_points.clear()      


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Counter()
    window.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    window.setMinimumSize(480, 380)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: Всё работает. Запустил у себя. Ищите `settings.ini` в рабочей директории (откуда запускаете код).

Comment: @МихаилМуругов не понимаю. у всех работает. файл ```settings.ini``` находится в той же папке. я даже в коде к нему путь указал. не работает. не сохраняет

Comment: Вы точно ищете в рабочей директории? Права на запись в неё есть?

Comment: записал в файл ini вручную, там не сохранилось. похоже нельзя переписывать файл
как это исправить? Точнее при следующем запуске программы файл обнуляется

Comment: Что значит **обнуляется**?

Comment: это значит что я записал имя игрока и очки, сохранил, перепроверил что оно там есть, запустил программу, написал в программе значения, запустил ini файл и обнаружил что все данные буквально стерлись

Comment: Так Вы и не записываете их. Вы в настройки записываете только `Name=Points`. Всё работает ровно так, как написано в коде.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109032/discussion-between-lcashe-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного изменил ваше приложение:

- перешел с виджета `QTableView` на виджет `QTableWidget`;
- реализовал свою сортировку по столбцу "Points" используя класс `QStyledItemDelegate`;
- добавил функциональность по нажатию кнопки "Sort";
- реализовал сохранение настроек приложения используя класс `QSettings`.

**QSettings** - это абстракция позволяющая вам сохранять и восстанавливать параметры приложения
в портативном режиме. Он также поддерживает пользовательские форматы хранения.
Я добавил некоторую раскраску ячеек таблицы, когда значение `point` больше `777`,
для того, чтобы продемонстрировать сохранение настроек, в том числе и цвета ячейки.

Объекты, задействованные в сохранение настроек, помечены комментарием `# QSettings`.
Пробуйте, но помните, что порядок написанных строк - имеет значение:

```
import sys
import contextlib
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SettingsManager:                                                           # QSettings
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.m_settings = QtCore.QSettings(filename, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

    @property
    def settings(self):
        return self.m_settings

    def read(self, widget):
        self.settings.beginGroup(widget.objectName())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            selectionMode = self.settings.value(
                "selectionMode", type=QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode
            )
            widget.setSelectionMode(selectionMode)

        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            rowCount = self.settings.value("rowCount", type=int)
            columnCount = self.settings.value("columnCount", type=int)
            widget.setRowCount(rowCount)
            widget.setColumnCount(columnCount)
            items = self.settings.value("items")
            if items is None:
                self.read_defaults(widget)
            else:
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                    i = stream.readInt()
                    j = stream.readInt()
                    stream >> it
                    widget.setItem(i, j, it)
                selecteditems = self.settings.value("selecteditems")
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                    selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly
                )
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    i = stream.readInt()
                    j = stream.readInt()
                    it = widget.item(i, j)
                    if it is not None:
                        it.setSelected(True)
        self.settings.endGroup()

    def write(self, widget):
        self.settings.beginGroup(widget.objectName())
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            self.settings.setValue("selectionMode", widget.selectionMode())

        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            self.settings.setValue("rowCount", widget.rowCount())
            self.settings.setValue("columnCount", widget.columnCount())
            items = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(items, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
            for i in range(widget.rowCount()):
                for j in range(widget.columnCount()):
                    it = widget.item(i, j)
                    if it is not None:
                        stream.writeInt(i)
                        stream.writeInt(j)
                        stream << it
            self.settings.setValue("items", items)
            selecteditems = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream = QtCore.QDataStream(
                selecteditems, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly
            )
            for it in widget.selectedItems():
                # print(it.row(), it.column())
                stream.writeInt(it.row())
                stream.writeInt(it.column())
            self.settings.setValue("selecteditems", selecteditems)
        self.settings.endGroup()

    def release(self):
        self.m_settings.sync()

    def read_defaults(self, widget):
        if  widget.objectName() == "tableWidget":
            widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
            widget.setRowCount(0)     #(1)
            widget.setColumnCount(2)


@contextlib.contextmanager                                                       # QSettings
def settingsContext(filename):
    manager = SettingsManager(filename)
    try:
        yield manager
    finally:
        manager.release()


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    colorChanged = pyqtSignal(int, int, int)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            value = index.data()
            editor = QLineEdit(parent)
            return editor        

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
            try:    value = int(value)
            except: value = 0
            editor.setText(f'{value:>20}')   

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
        editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            try:    value = int(editor.text())
            except: value = 0
            value = f'{value:>20}'  
            model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)
            self.colorChanged.emit(index.row(), index.column(), int(value))  


class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name" , "Points"])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        
        delegate = Delegate(self)
        delegate.colorChanged.connect(self.color_changed)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)     

        update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update")                           
        update_button.clicked.connect(self.on_update_button)                      
        self.sort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sort")
        self.sort_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.sort_button.toggled.connect(self.on_sort_button)  

        self.qlineedit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit_name.resize(24, 80)
        self.qlineedit_points = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit_points.resize(24, 80)

        horisontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit_name, stretch=1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit_points, stretch=1)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(update_button)                                 
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.sort_button)
        horisontal_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid_layout.addLayout(horisontal_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0)  
       
        self.read_settings()                                                     # QSettings
        
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)                     
        self.tableWidget.sortItems(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)

    def color_changed(self, row, col, value):
        if value > 777:
            color = QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256)
            self.tableWidget.item(row, col).setBackground(color)
            self.tableWidget.item(row, col).setFont(QFont("Consolas", 10, QFont.Bold))
        else:
            self.tableWidget.item(row, col).setBackground(QColor("#fff"))
            self.tableWidget.item(row, col).setFont(QFont("Consolas", 10))         

    def on_update_button(self):
        name = self.qlineedit_name.text().strip()
        point = self.qlineedit_points.text().strip() if self.qlineedit_points.text().strip() else '0'
        if not point.isdigit():
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните правильно поле ввода Points!')
            return msg
        if not name:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните поле ввода Name!')
            return msg
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        rows  = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        add_record = True

        for row in range(rows):
            if name == self.tableWidget.item(row, 0).text():
                #print(name)
                add_record = False
                row_edit = row
                break

        if add_record:       
            if self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes():  
                row = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()[-1].row()
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row+1)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(name))      
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(f'{point:>20}'))
                self.color_changed(row+1, 1, int(point))
            else:
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(rows)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 0, QTableWidgetItem(name))       
                self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 1, QTableWidgetItem(f'{point:>20}'))
                self.color_changed(rows, 1, int(point))
        else:                 
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_edit, 1, QTableWidgetItem(f'{point:>20}'))
            self.color_changed(row_edit, 1, int(point))

        self.qlineedit_name.clear()
        self.qlineedit_points.clear()      
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        
    def on_sort_button(self, state):
        if state: self.tableWidget.sortItems(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        else:     self.tableWidget.sortItems(1, Qt.AscendingOrder)

    def closeEvent(self, event):                                                 # QSettings
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)    
        self.write_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def read_settings(self):                                                     # QSettings
        with settingsContext("data_table_widget.ini") as m:
            for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                if children.objectName():
                    m.read(children)

    def write_settings(self):                                                    # QSettings
        with settingsContext("data_table_widget.ini") as m:
            for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                if children.objectName():
                    m.write(children)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Consolas", 10)) 
    app.setStyle('Fusion')                     
    w = Counter()
    w.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    w.setMinimumSize(480, 380)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже думал подучивать sql. Премного благодарен

Comment: @Lcashe  Вы правильно мыслили. Всегда надо иметь несколько вариантов. Простым способом реализации является использование базы данных, и хорошим вариантом в этом случае является использование `sqlite`. Советую вам реализовать и вашу задумку.

Comment: @S.Nick от sql все отталкивает миграция схемы